# fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I keep getting the same error message...
*Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object*
I've tried:
- removing quotes from ':user' and ':pass'
- changing `fetch()` to `fetchAll()`
- using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

I can't seem to find a question that solves this, they all are solid SQL statements, there's no variables inside them.

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ':user' AND password= ':pass' ");
    $q -> bindParam(':user', $username);
    $q -> bindParam(':pass', $password);
    $result = $q -> execute();
    $numrows = count($result);
    echo $numrows;
    if($numrows == 1){
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $row["id"] = $_SESSION["id"];
            $row["username"] = $_SESSION["username"];
            $row["password"] = $_SESSION["password"];
            $row["email"] = $_SESSION["email"];
        }
    } else {
        header("location: index.php?p=5");
    }
```

Comment: Here's the thing, if it fails it returns `false`, and `count(false)` is actually `1`, if it succeeds it returns `true`, and `count(true)` is also `1`,  you need better error checking.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure they switched from `mysql_*` api and mistakenly believe that pdo statement `execute` will also return a result set just like `mysql_query` does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch should be used on the PDOstatement object.

According to the [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set

The `fetch` function is a member function of the PDOStatement object.
Example from the manual:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute(); //no need in another variable, like: $r = $sth->

/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //$sth, not "$r"
```

**Another note:**
Regarding your usage of `execute`, according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it returns a boolean value (true/false) and not an array of values.

I believe you've used mySQL so the "migration" to PDO is a bit strange for you, look at the manual and follow some tutorials.

Comment: And when they say `$result = $q -> execute();` then `$result` is not what they think it is, it can only be `TRUE/FALSE`. `execute()` returns a `bool` not a result set.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quote from `user` and `pass`

```
$q = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :user AND password= :pass");
```